# Filter a Postgres Table based on multiple columns

Tags: sql, node.js, json, postgresql

I'm working on an shopping website. User selects multiple filters on and sends the request to backend which is in node.js and using postgres as DB.
So I want to search the required data in a single query.
I have a json object containing all the filters that user selected. I want to use them in postgres query and return to user the obtained results.

I have a postgres Table that contains a few products.

```
name         Category      Price
------------------------------
LOTR          Books        50
Harry Potter  Books        30
Iphone13      Mobile       1000
SJ8           Cameras      200
```

I want to filter the table using n number of filters in a single query.

I have to make it work for multiple filters such as the ones mentioned below. So I don't have to write multiple queries for different filters.

```
{ category: 'Books', price: '50' }
{ category: 'Books' }
{category : ['Books', 'Mobiles']}
```

I can query the table using

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE category='Books' AND 'price'='100'
SELECT * FROM products WHERE category='Books'
SELECT * FROM products WHERE category='Books' OR category='Mobiles'
```

respectively.
But I want to write my query in such a way that it populates the Keys and Values dynamically. So I may not have to write separate query for every filter.

I have obtained the key and value pairs from the request.query and saved them

```
const params = req.query;
const keys: string = Object.keys(params).join(",")
const values: string[] = Object.values(params)

const indices = Object.keys(params).map((obj, i) => {
  return "$" + (i + 1)
})
```

But I'm unable to pass them in the query in a correct manner.

Does anybody have a suggestion for me? I'd highly appreciate any help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way you filter data from a SQL database table.

You need to use the NodeJS pg driver to connect to the database, then write a `SQL` query. I recommend prepared statements.

A query would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE price < ...
```

At least based on your question, to me, it is unclear why would want to do these manipulations in JavaScript, nor what you want to be accomplished really.

Comment: I have updated my question. Does this make it a bit clear now?